# What to do with all the similar question about hash collisions, Birthday Paradox, "How random is random sampling/RNG?"

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

The following questions are all essentially about the same underlying concept, albeit in different wordings; we get new variants every month. How to handle this situation? There is no good dupe target, for the reasons below.

- they are asked across various languages, but most are fairly or totally language-agnostic
- Re hashing collisions, some questions are simply about calculating/estimating the collision probability; others are about tweaking the parameters or hashing scheme to minimize it
- Re Birthday Paradox, some are about the literal Birthday Paradox per se (N people with 1/365 pairwise-probability of sharing a birthday). Some are about the BP meaning RNGs or random sampling from an integer range or list, specifically about the expectation of repetitions, or whether the occurrence of repetitions implies a bad RNG.

## Examples

- [How do I assess the hash collision probability?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/862346/how-do-i-assess-the-hash-collision-probability)
- [Hash collision worries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213709/hash-collision-worries)
- [Random is barely random at all?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145510/random-is-barely-random-at-all) [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python)
- [How random is Random.Next()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334811/how-random-is-random-next) [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23)
- [Birthday Paradox: How to programmatically estimate the probability of 3, and N, people sharing a birthday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4990164/birthday-paradox-how-to-programmatically-estimate-the-probability-of-3-people-s) [language-agnostic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-agnostic)
- *plenty more...*

Comment: The same way we deal with other kinds of duplicates: select a good old question, edit it to downplay the non generic parts, then close the others as duplicates of it.

Comment: @Raedwald: then you haven't read any of the questions I cited. There is no good dupe target. (If there was, I wouldn't have asked this)

Comment: If you know the answer, answer. If that answer also answers any other questions in your list, vote to dupe close. Just do the usual stuff. Doing nothing is also among the options.

Comment: Write an appropriate canonical duplicate, if you can't find one.